# Конвертировать столбец "расстояние до метро"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

В столбце расстояние до метро встречаются значения с "мин" "м" и "км"

[image: Расстояние до метро]

Как конвертировать из string в int или float, удалив "мин" и перевести "км" в "м"?

Есть:

```
        Расстояние до метро 
0             1294 м.       
1             510 м.         
2             12 мин, 1 км         
3             41 мин, 12 км         
4             3 мин, 280 м
```

Нужно:

```
          Расстояние до метро 
0             1294       
1             510         
2             1000         
3             12000         
4             280
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

исходный DF:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
  Расстояние до метро
0             1294 м.
1              510 м.
2        12 мин, 1 км
3       41 мин, 12 км
4        3 мин, 280 м
```

решение:

```
to_repl = [r"\d+\s*мин,?\s*", r"\s*км\.?", r"\s*м\.?"]
val = ["", "000", ""]

df["dist"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Расстояние до метро"]
                             .replace(to_repl, val, regex=True), 
                           errors="coerce")
```

результат:

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]:
  Расстояние до метро   dist
0             1294 м.   1294
1              510 м.    510
2        12 мин, 1 км   1000
3       41 мин, 12 км  12000
4        3 мин, 280 м    280

In [74]: df.dtypes
Out[74]:
Расстояние до метро    object
dist                    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: ух ты!
огромное спасибо, кучу времени на это потратил.

как в этом разобраться? может есть статьи какие по таким символам? а то не гуглится, а уметь обязательно надо

[r"\d+\s*мин,?\s*", r"\s*км\.?", r"\s*м\.?"]

Comment: @Aisys, Это регулярные выражения... Поищите книжку / туториал по Regular Expressions... ;)